# Trying to get a sorted list in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, sorting, enumerable

I have two list boxes (Available Items & Selected Items) which are populated from a database.  I'm able to add and remove via buttons between these lists but, when I remove from the Selected list, the item goes to the bottom of the Available list. It does not get alphabetized. So I'm trying a Linq option.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable2[System.Object,System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem]'.
```

**Code:**

```
Imports System.Linq
        'After adding the item to the list sort it
        Dim myQuery As IEnumerable(Of ListItem)

        myQuery = From result In Available.Items _
            Select result _
            Order By result.Text Ascending
        'Rebuild the list
        Available.Items.Clear()
        For Each item In myQuery
            Available.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ListItemCollection` returned by `Items` only implements `IEnumerable`, and not `IEnumerable(Of ListItem)`, you should add a `Cast` to your query.  You will also want to use `ToList()`, or something else that forces evaluation of the query, before you clear it, since LINQ queries are lazily evaluated, and otherwise the list will be cleared before your query is evaluated!

```vb
myQuery = (
    From result In Available.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)() _
    Select result _
    Order By result.Text Ascending
).ToList()
```

You may also want to turn `Option Strict On` to help find additional 
issues at compile time.

Comment: or simply write `Dim query = Aggregate result As ListItem In Available.Items Order By result.Text Into ToList`

Comment: @Sehnsucht Thanks for that - I had never seen the Aggregate syntax before.  Looking through [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531251.aspx) now.  Thanks again for teaching me something new! :-)

Comment: @Sehnsucht I appreciate the suggestion.